# Is it possible to define links to other files in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022, xml-documentation

I have a class `FooViewData.cs` that serves as a ViewModel for a `Foo.cshtml`.  It's also related tangentially to a foo.sql, foo.css, foo.js, etc...

When I am inside `FooViewData.cs`, I'd like to be able to click a link and jump to `foo.js` for instance.

I see that XML comments support tags like `<see cref=".."/>`, so I tried setting as `<see cref="..\wwwroot\js\foo.js"/>`, but Visual Studio doesn't appear to do anything about it.

Does Visual Studio have a feature that allows you to link from file to file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, unfortunately.

It *is* possible to put an `href` in there, if you want to reference a URL for people to open in a browser:

```
/// <see href="https://stackoverflow.com/q/75762355/120955" />
```

But if you try putting local file names and such in the href, it doesn't open the file when you click through to the link. Nor does it update the comment if you rename the file.

Comment: Oddly enough, it offers to open up the file if you provide full path.  `<see href="file:///C:/Code/Git/cpm-web/main/Web.UI/ViewDataModels/Section1129ViewData.cs"/>`.  Holding down Ctrl and clicking it fires off a new instance of Visual Studio with this file open.  Of course, I'd need a relative path, not an absolute one.

Answer (score 1):

You can not unfortunately

You could use a href to reference a url that will open a browser for the people